# Convert pymongo millisecond to different format

Tags: python, pymongo

I'm attempting to convert `1614100501543` of type 'bson.int64.Int64' to a formatted date using `datetime`:

The below code:

```
print(results[0][0] , type(results[0][0]))

print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(results[0][0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

returns :

```
1614100501543 <class 'bson.int64.Int64'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-142-97decf382ca6> in <module>
      1 print(results[0][0] , type(results[0][0]))
      2 
----> 3 print(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(results[0][0]).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))

ValueError: year 53118 is out of range
```

How to set the DateTime correctly to allow correct conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`utcfromtimestamp()` expects an epoch in seconds, but you are supplying an epoch in milliseconds.

Divide the number by 1000 and it will work.

```
x = 1614100501543
d = datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x / 1000)
print(d)
```

prints

```
2021-02-23 17:15:01.543000
```